# Drag and drop picture to explorer

Tags: c#, picturebox, drag, explorer

I try to drag and drop picture from picture box to Windows Explorer, but file just does not copy.
Maybe because the PictureBox is in custom Controller drop doesn't work? 
The temporary file saves successfully.

```
private void _picBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
            var pic = (PictureBox) sender;
            pic.Image.Save(@"tmp.jpg");
            var files = new string[] {@"tmp.jpg"};
            var res = pic.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files), DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
            MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your application?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: I dont have any exception. I wrote that till pic.Image.Save("tmp.jpg"); line is all ok. I really dont know wtf happened it's just should work and it don't.

Comment: Also I cant debug my project because it cannot load symbols. I had try to fix this problem, but...

Comment: Maybe you should try to create a small test project to isolate your drag&drop problem from the rest of your project.

Comment: In NEW project this code works like a charm.

Comment: I found that I should set full paths. I fix code in question. Tnx everybody for response.

Comment: Try putting your answer in the answer box, not in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works only with full paths

```
 private void _picBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
     {
        var programFullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var programDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(programFullPath);
        var pic = (PictureBox) sender;
        pic.Image.Save(programDirectory+ @"\tmp.jpg");
        var files = new string[] {programDirectory+ @"\tmp.jpg"};
        var res = pic.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files), DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
        MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
    }
 }
```